# FORTRAN 77 NEQNF IMSL Solver, 2 variables, 6 equations

Tags: fortran, solver, imsl

I am trying to use NEQNF to solve a system of 6 non linear equations. I need to determine 2 variables to solve my system. According to [description](http://www.roguewave.com/Portals/0/products/imsl-numerical-libraries/fortran-library/docs/6.0/math/default.htm?turl=neqnf.htm)  i need to define "N" which is the length of "X"(variables) AND "F"(equations).

Does this mean that i can use this solver only if X=F? Because N is defindes as an integer in the example given below in the description.

Or can i define N as a vector? How does declaration of N supposed to look like in this case?

Answer (score 0):

From the link you gave:

> X – The point at which the functions are evaluated.   (Input) X should
>   not be changed by FCN.
>
> F – The computed function values at the point X.   (Output)
>
> N — Length of X and F.

`X` and `F` are vectors of length `N` (scalar!). `X` is the input to `FCN`, and `F` the output. So I would guess that `F` is (generally) not equal to `X`.

Comment: UNLSF Solver is suitable for this problem.

Topic can be closed.

Thanks.